# Enabling notification sound for all stuff in GNOME

Tags: gnome, sound, notification

I think Title of topic is transparent enough. How can I configure GNOME to play notification sound for each notification?

*I also Google it but no luck on my way*

Comment: Did you see this: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/sound-alert.html.en

Comment: Yes! It's just for some certain or specified notification but I want to enable it on a wide range including battery-low and battery-critical (gnome default behavior don't support this, so I'm looking for a away for it, any ideas? (_Also I'm so sorry for this late respond_) @WillemK hope for a reply :D, or maybe I should open a new topic. thanks for your comment anyway!

Comment: Slack and Discord make a sound with every gnome notification. So it's clearly the application's job to do so. That being said, it'd be nice to have a default notification sound

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a small background program to solve this problem for myself:

https://gitlab.com/dbazile/gaudible

If you're handy with Python, you should be able to copy and extend it to cover all of the notification categories you're interested in.

Comment: Nice tool. Thanks